# Login to website using another computer for authenticating

Tags: login, browser, authentication, cookie

I have two Ubuntu machines which I would like to access StackExchange from. I am currently logged in from one. But the other I do not trust enough to let it see my password.

Is there a way for me to get a browser on the second computer logged on StackExchange while only allowing the first trusted computer see my password?

Overwriting the entire browser profile on the second computer is not an option for me since it always has cookies, browsing history, and open tabs, which I do not want to lose.

Comment: How deep is your distrust? Do you distrust the kernel on that machine or just the/some user-space software? Do you distrust the firmware or the hardware? Do you distrust the system's administrator(s)? Is your distrust rooted in malignancy or just incompetence?

Comment: Asking from a different angle: what do you fear may happen if somebody gets a hold of your StackExchange account password in terms of damage?

Comment: @DavidFoerster I trust it enough to allow it access to my cookies for StackExchange but not enough to allow it access to my password for the site. My wording of the question is such that I would not trust even the OS or the hardware with the password. Though an answer given under the assumption that I trust the OS and hardware but do not trust the user account running the browser would be useful enough for me to be accepted as well.

Comment: Alternative solution to the same effect: change your SE password every time after you use it on the untrusted machine. This way you can contain the impact of a hypothetical password compromise to the same time span as the validity of the access token stored on the machine inside the cookie. That means the method is just as secure as but easier to implement than copying cookies around (provided the passwords aren't predictable and you don't reuse them anywhere else).

Comment: @DavidFoerster If my password was compromised an attacker could change my password. But just being logged in should not be enough to change my password. I would like the end state to be the same as if I had simply logged in by typing my username and password on the less trusted machine. But without the possibility of any software on that machine capturing the password in the process.

Comment: What would they gain from changing your account password though in addition to the complete access to your account that they have already? You can always reset the password vie e-mail and, even though it's possible to change the e-mail address with knowledge of the password, the old address will be notified of the change with a restoration link.

Comment: @DavidFoerster You seem to be claiming that from a security perspective it makes no difference whether an adversary acquires the password or just a cookie. Yet all security professionals seems to agree that storing the plaintext password in a cookie instead of using a session cookie would be an unforgivable sin.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52209/discussion-between-david-foerster-and-kasperd).